# Evaluating the norm of $\mathfrak I : E \to E$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, banach-spaces

I'm having some trouble with the following exercise:

> Let $E=\mathcal C([a,b])$ be the set of continuous maps $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ with the supremum norm. Let $x\in E$ and define $\mathfrak{I}x\in E$ as $$(\mathfrak{I}x)(t)=\int_a^tx(s)ds$$
>
> Prove that:
>
> 1. $\mathfrak I\in L(E)$  (The set of linear continuous maps from $E$ to itself with the norm   $\|f\|=\sup\limits_{\|x\|\leq1} \|f(x)\|$) and evaluate $\|\mathfrak I\|$.
> 2. Show that $\mathfrak I$ has no eigenvalues.

I was able to prove (2) and in the first one, I managed to prove that $\mathfrak I \in L(E)$ and although I was able to find an upper bound to $\|\mathfrak I\|$, I wasn't able to evaluate its precise value.

How can this be done?

Comment: The norm is $b-a$ and it is attained when $x\equiv 1$.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but the ideas from this post (part b) can be used to solve your problem  [Show that the operator $(Af)(x)=\int_0^x f(t) \, dt$ is continuous and find the norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2345181/show-that-the-operator-afx-int-0x-ft-dt-is-continuous-and-find-the)

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2997663/121671) is a similar problem

Answer (score 4):

You can bound: $$\left|\int_a^t x\right|\le(t-a)\|x\|\le(b-a)\|x\|$$

So, the norm of your operator is less than or equal to $b-a$. But, as Geetha mentions, taking $x$ to be a nonzero constant function shows the norm is precisely $(b-a)$.

That’s because if an operator $T$ has $\|T\|\le N$ and $\|Tx\|=N\|x\|$ for some $x$, then $\|T\|=N$. This is a straightforward fact.

Answer (score 2):

A more general fact holds. Assume a linear operator $T: C[a,b]\to C[a,b]$ is positive, i.e. for $f\ge 0$ we have $Tf\ge 0.$ Then $T$ is bounded and $\|T\|=\|T1\|_\infty.$ Indeed for any $f\in C[a,b]$ we have $\|f\|_\infty 1\pm f\ge 0.$ Hence $$\|f\|_\infty T1\pm Tf=T(\|f\|_\infty 1\pm f)\ge 0$$ Thus $$|Tf|\le \|f\|_\infty T1$$ which implies $$\|Tf\|_\infty \le \|T1\|_\infty \|f\|_\infty\ {\rm and }\ \|T\|\le \|T1\|_\infty$$ The converse inequality $\|T\|\ge \|T1\|_\infty $ holds obviously, which means the norm is attained at $f\equiv 1.$